# How can I get the content of a cell in a grid in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid

I need to get the content of cell in a `Grid` in C#. Is there a way to do something like this?

```
UIElement element = MyGrid.Children.getElementAt(x, y)
```

Comment: Are x and y screen coordinates or row and column indices?

Answer (score 11):

You could use Linq:

```
// using System.Linq;

var element = grid.Children.Cast<UIElement>().
    FirstOrDefault(e => Grid.GetColumn(e) == x && Grid.GetRow(e) == y);
```

or if there is more than one element in the specified cell:

```
var elements = grid.Children.Cast<UIElement>().
    Where(e => Grid.GetColumn(e) == x && Grid.GetRow(e) == y);
```

where elements is an `IEnumerable<UIElement>`.